# Saving fields after a raster join with python arcgis

Tags: arcpy, raster, attribute-joins

I am working on a raster processing script in which i join a categorical raster with a table that includes some extra data on each category.  After much hassle, I have the join working, but I can't seem to save the raster with the fields included.  I would like to be able to use the lookup tool by field name later on my script.

Here is my code.

```
AddJoin_management("joinedRaster", "VALUE", "joinTable", "joinField")
F = Raster("joinedRaster")
F.save("Ras_j")
```

If I try to do:

```
fieldList = ListFields(F)
for field in fieldList:
     print("{0} is a type of {1} with a length of {2}"
        .format(field.name, field.type, field.length))
```

with F, then I see that join has been completed successfully.  But if I try to do:

```
a = Raster("Ras_j")
```

Then I only see the fields from the original raster dataset, without the joined fuels.  Any advice on how to make sure that the join persists?

Comment: The RAT (Raster Attribute Table) is special, you can't export to it - only from. Try adding the fields required, joining and calculating the values using calculate field.

Comment: You might want a [Lookup tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/lookup.htm). Or if you really want all your fields into another RAT, alter a file `your_raster.img.vat.dbf` or whatever you use.